# Cloth collisions with another cloth

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, collision

I am trying to create a scene where a cloth will collide with another cloth;
The error is where the clothes are interacting and after that is going wrong....
I have attached here the blender project:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iYXjxMVHKUPsjYT9fv76l3W86nseNzWu/view?usp=sharing

This is an example, my project is more complicated, here I uploaded something more simplified as a reference.

How can I solve this problem?

I expect that things will work like in real life, just like throwing two clothes on top of each other at the same time, they will sit on the ground, now they are flying in the air

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: i just downloaded your file...but i am not sure, what you would expect to happen?

Comment: ...proposal: untick single sided for both cloth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I followed the Chris answer and I unchecked "Single Sided" and it works